# Nativebase Picker Item not showing Selected value

Tags: react-native, native-base

I am trying to select item from picker item. problem is when i clicked on item then on function handler `onValueChangeJob(value)` perform some task

```
onValueChangeJob(value) {
    this.setState({ jobValue: value.jobTitle})
       USE value.number form another task
    });
}
```

Below is my picker component

```
<Picker
 style={commonStyle.pickerStyle}
 textStyle={commonStyle.textStylePicker}
 headerTitleStyle={commonStyle.headerTitleStyle}
 headerBackButtonTextStyle={commonStyle.headerBackButtonTextStyle}
 iosIcon={<Icon name="ios-arrow-down" />}
 mode="dropdown"
 placeholder="MAKE A SELECTION"
 placeholderStyle={commonStyle.placeholderStyle}
 note={false}
 itemTextStyle={commonStyle.itemTextStyle}
 selectedValue={this.state.jobValue}
 onValueChange={this.onValueChangeJob.bind(this)}
 >
 {jobItems}                                    
</Picker>
```

While The jobitems coming from map which created in render() function like

```
jobItems = this.state.jobTypesList.map((v,i) => {
    return <Picker.Item key={i} value={v} label={v.jobTitle} />
});
```

So here if I used directly in picker.item props value-{v.jobTitle} then selected value change but i want to use whole object v in onValueChangeJob(value) function. One main thing **state update but cant displaying on selected value of picker** 
tried lots of different things but not happening the thing what i want.
how should i handle this with proper example as i am new in react native.

Look at how my picker looks in this image

[image: Look How My Picker look in this image]

Comment: You're setting `jobValue` (object) as `jobTitle` (string probably) and then accessing it from Picker `selectedValue`, which expects an object, not a string. What about `this.setState({ jobValue: value})` in onValueChangeJob()?

Comment: Thanks For Your Response i know that i setting object but this.setState({ jobValue: value. jobTitle }) but why this cant work ? means it worked state value of jobValue updated but cant displayed on selectedValue={this.state.jobValue} Picker.

Comment: Picker items are JobTypes. You're telling picker to select a JobTitle, which is not in its array of JobTypes, so how could it know which item it is referring to?

Comment: Jobtitle is present in JobTypeList ....

Answer (score 0):

After lots of googling on one solution i find that solution that i have to filter this.state.jobTypesList this array on onValueChange handler and grab objects of particular job Title

```
return this.state.jobTypesList.map((v,i) => {
            return <Picker.Item key={i} value={v.jobTitle} label={v.jobTitle} 
        });

let filterArray = this.state.jobTypesList.filter((v) => v.jobTitle === value)[0]
filterArray.jobTitle
filterArray.jobNumber
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [yup](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@hookform/resolvers) schema and validations, then you can use getValues() in *selectedValue* property.

I resolved it by

```
<Picker
      selectedValue = {getValues('storeId')}
      onValueChange={itemValue =>
           setValue('storeId', itemValue, true)
      }>
  .../>
```